# Why is Oracle's dbms_metadata.get_ddl returning different results?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm trying to compare two schemas using dbms_metadata.get_ddl. The two schemas were created using exactly the same SQL scripts. However on one primary key I'm getting a difference in the DDLs:

```
ALTER TABLE "SCHEMA_NAME"."AUDIT_EVENTS_LOG" ADD CONSTRAINT "AUDIT_EVENTS_LOG_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("LOG_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DATA_INDEX"  ENABLE
```

Vs:

```
  ALTER TABLE "SCHEMA_NAME"."AUDIT_EVENTS_LOG" ADD CONSTRAINT "AUDIT_EVENTS_LOG_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("LOG_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  TABLESPACE "DATA_INDEX"  ENABLE
```

Both schemas are located on the same database instance. The script for creating this primary key, used for both schemas, is:

```
ALTER TABLE "AUDIT_EVENTS_LOG" ADD CONSTRAINT "AUDIT_EVENTS_LOG_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("LOG_ID")
  USING INDEX  TABLESPACE "DATA_INDEX" ENABLE;
```

What could cause the difference in result for GET_DDL, when both are created using exactly the same script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM`, particularly the `STORAGE` param.

It looks like your first call to `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL` had it enabled (which is the default setting), but the second call did not.

If you care about getting the exact same results each time, then take care to call `SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM` ahead of time for every setting that affects your output.